# How to use 2 different ckEditor5 in one build

Tags: angular, ckeditor5, custom-build

I am following this link(documentation) but it is not working.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#creating-super-builds

When I create a build using 2 different ckEditros(ckEditor5) it give me following error.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.editor.create is not a function
TypeError: this.editor.create is not a function
at CKEditorComponent.

[image]

please guide me about that problem if anyone knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

use different

> id

for each CKEditor.

if the issue still persists then try sharing some code so i can see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. You can install two versions of same `npm` modules. First of all, delete the existing version and install using this command and you can provide the version number to install it. This is the command:

```
npm i <package_name_alias>@npm:<package_name>
```

In your case, it should become this(for latest version):

```
npm i latest-ckEditor5@npm:ckEditor5
```

And for any other version lower than the latest use this:

```
npm i latest-ckEditor5@npm:ckEditor5@versionNumber
```

In your package, it will look something like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "latest-ckEditor5": "^latestPackage",
    "oldest-ckEditor5": "Olderverion"
  }
```

You can use them like this:

```
import { ckEditor5 } from 'latest-ckEditor5'; // check the exported member name
import { ckEditor5 } from 'oldest-ckEditor5';
```